# Overlay multiple JSliders in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jslider

Is it possible to overlay multiple JSliders so I can see the "thumbs" on both (I've tried disabling the painting of the track and setting opacity to false but one still hides the other)? Basically I'd like to create a component that allows the user to define a range (and I didn't really want to write a custom one since it has most of the attributes of a slider). If there is another way I could do that with a slider, that would work too.

thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Perhaps you could define your range using JSpinners instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to use the slider mechanism for this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I found it (i must not have been seraching on the right terms). Swing labs as a JXMultiThumbSlider that I think will do the trick.

http://swinglabs.org/hudson/job/SwingX%20Weekly%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXMultiThumbSlider.html

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem, I wanted a slider with two thumbs. I didn't get into it too much, and what I ended up doing to get the range is simply putting two sliders and in the "onSliderChange" event listener prevented one beeing smaller than the other and the other bigger than the one. I don't beleive Swing has a two-thumb-Slider, although it might be a cool new feature to add, so I think this is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

JIDE has a RangeSlider with 2 thumbs (and a nice extra one on top to move both thumbs at once (e.g. drag the range around) in their open source common layer: http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm