# Multi-value JSlider component?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jslider

I need a multi-value JSlider (or a similar component) for an analysis application. The two features missing from the regular JSlider are the ability to have more than one knob and also the ability to add or remove knobs on the fly. The reason for this is that they will be used to partition the 0..100% range for a particular factor into two or more subranges which are fed into a binning algorithm.

After some unsuccessful googling, it seems I'll have to develop a custom component (which I'm not very good at, I've been coding in Java for 10 years, but have zero experience in Swing). Is it possible to extend (easily :-) the JSlider component? Or are there better alternatives, perhaps not Swing-based but web-based? I have some flexibility in selecting the GUI approach for this. The current analysis application is command-line so a Swing GUI would be most straighforward, but nothing really prevents me for turning it into a web app if need be.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335170/overlay-multiple-jsliders-in-swing

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JXMultiThumbSlider in [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/).